# How can I keep my iMessage on iPhone, but stop them coming through on my Mac?

Tags: macos, icloud, messages, apple-id

I don't want my private messages popping up on my Mac, so is there a way I can remove my account on my Mac, but keep it on my iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

Open Messages and open the preferences.

Select the Apple ID you want to delete and then sign out.

No more messages should arrive from that point on. You could reboot if you want to be sure things are reset.

Comment: yes but then imessage wont work on my phone! i want it on my phone but not on my mac

Comment: @CallumOliver Not true. If you delete one iMessage on one device - that message remains on all other devices. Same with deleting the entire account from one device. You won't affect iMessage on your iPhone in any way signing in or out of it on the Mac.